# Linking files into TeXnicCenter: main file, .eps figures, and a .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, texniccenter

I am trialling TeXnicCenter 2 on files used by LyX 2, with the latter linking all files and producing correct PDF output.

My files are an `article` class file, a number of `.eps` figures, and a `.bib` file created in JabRef.

My problem is trying to build a project within TeXnicCenter 2 that can link the three file types and produce a successful PDF output. How do I tell my project in TeXnicCenter 2 to access the necessary files ?

So, I have a file management issue - an example would be great.

Comment: Are your `.tex`, `.eps` and `.bib` files all in the same folder? What kind of (problematic) output do you receive?

Answer (score 2):

Let us say your main file for your project in TeXnicCenter has the name `mwe.tex` in directory `xyz`.

Copy the following code in the directory `xyz` with the name `mwe.tcp` (`tcp` stands for TeXnicCenter Project):

```
[FormatInfo]
Type=TeXnicCenterProjectInformation
Version=4

[ProjectInfo]
MainFile=mwe.tex
UseBibTeX=1
UseMakeIndex=1
ActiveProfile=LaTeX ⇨ SumatraPdf
ProjectLanguage=de
ProjectDialect=DE
```

Change `UseMakeIndex` and `UseMakeIndex` to zero, if you need not to use creating a bibliography and an index. `ActiveProfile` names the way TeXnicCenter builds your pdf file (change it if necceccary after you have opend TeXnicCenter and choose other way to compile). Change `ProjectLanguage` and `ProjectDialect` to what you use.

Now open file `mwe.tcp` with doubleclick in the windows explorer. TeXnicCenter opens and shows file `mwe.tex` On the left side of TeXnicCenter you can switch the navigation bar to `files`to show the files TeXnicCenter can found to be called in your main TeX file. If TeXnicCenter can not localise all of your files  you can load them one time by your own. Use `File` -> `Open` to open the other files for your project.  TeXnicCenter adds the information about all loaded files in a file `mwe.tpc`.

Please remember: TeXnicCenter can only build a pdf file, if all files are compilable for MiKTeX. TeXnicCenter is not able to execute LyX code!.